# Posting an image to a Facebook event wall/feed? Not as a link based update.

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have searched the facebook API documentation and we cannot figure out how to post an image to a Facebook event wall feed.

I have only been able to post a link based update.  I do not want to change the cover photo or profile picture, but I do want users to be able to upload an image post to their event wall.

I have had no problem making this work for facebook profiles, groups and pages.  Not sure why events would work differently :/

If anyone can show me where in the Facebook API this is possible it would be massively appreciated!

Thanks :)

Comment: According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/event/photos, this should work pretty much like posting photos to any other object.

Comment: I seem to only be able to get a link based post from this. I must be doing something wrong. Thanks for the link and speedy response :)